# Get data with a foreach from another table

Tags: php, foreach, php-5.3

I have the following code :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 89783187
        [level] => 1
        [score] => 8952
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 100563554
        [level] => 1
        [score] => 8034
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 98857523
        [level] => 1
        [score] => 744
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 76413076
        [level] => 2
        [score] => 6944
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 100287731
        [level] => 2
        [score] => 6570
    )
```

)
Now I want to create a array that will have the following structure, like this :

```
Array
(
 [1] => Array
      (
       [1] => Array
         (
           [id] => 1212
           [level]=>34343
           [score]=>878
         )
        [2] => Array
         (
            [id] => 23
            [level]=>878
            [score]=>76
         )
      )
  [2] => Array
     ...........
```

I tried with a `foreach` loop but it did not work. Can you help me please ? Thanks in advance and sorry for my English

Comment: post what you tried, also what did not work did you get any error? or a different result

Comment: Show us what you have tried, also, does each outer array contain two inner arrays or is there other requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for you

```
<?php 
$array =array(0=>array('id'=>1,'level'=>1,'score'=>111),1=>array('id'=>2,'level'=>2,'score'=>222),2=>array('id'=>3,'level'=>3,'score'=>333),3=>array('id'=>4,'level'=>4,'score'=>444));
$new_array =array_chunk($array,2);
print_r($new_array);
?>
```

This will Output

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [level] => 1
                        [score] => 111
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [level] => 2
                        [score] => 222
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [level] => 3
                        [score] => 333
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 4
                        [level] => 4
                        [score] => 444
                    )

            )

    )
```